# Giving a CSS Class to Echoing Strings

Tags: php, css, echo

I've a PHP file which has numerous echo statements for various checks like this;

```
if ($power != "1")
{
    echo "Please contact administrator for assistance.";
    exit;
}

if (!$uid)
{
    echo "You do not have permissions to change your status.";
    exit;
}

if (!$mybb->input['custom'])
{
    echo "You've not added any status to change";
    exit;
}
```

I want to give a similar CSS class to each echo statement. I tried this;

```
if ($power != "1")
{
    echo "<div class='class_name'>Please contact administrator for assistance.</div>";
    exit;
}
```

and it works, but my php file has dozens of echo's and I don't want to edit each and every echo statement. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Write a script to edit the .php file as text...

Comment: Good example of why to set the output logic in one place and the actual output somewhere else. Why not replace all echoes with a function you pass the message and class to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having issues/errors in above answers then here is my answer, I hope it helps;

Add the following code just above the `<?php` of your PHP file;

```
<style type="text/css">
    .error{
        background: #FFC6C6;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: Tahoma;
        border: 1px solid #F58686;
        padding: 3px 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Next change each `echo` statement to something like this;

```
echo "<div class='error'>Write error code here.</div>";
exit;
```

You can easily find and replace the echo statements if you're using Notepad++

It should work. Also its somewhat similar to MrCode's answer however I think my answer is easily understandable and may be easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you once again! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function to handle outputting the message. You'll have to update the existing code but in the future, you'll be able to change the CSS class name or HTML structure easily be modifying the function.

```
class Response
{
    public static function output($message, $className = 'class_name')
    {
        echo "<div class='" . htmlspecialchars($className) . "'>" . $message. "</div>";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if ($power != "1")
{
    Response::output("Please contact administrator for assistance.");
}
```

Override the class name:

```
Response::output("Please contact administrator for assistance.", "other_class");
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The benefit of the refit of all output messages now is that new messages in the future are easier add. Go a step further and have the message mapped to a constant from a list of possible messages and it gets even easier, as changing the actual wording can all be done in one place.

Comment: Exactly, plus the mapped messages would make it easier to implement multiple languages in future.

Comment: Didn't want to even mention that for fear of blowing people's minds!

Comment: I have used this but it shows this error;
`Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`

What is going wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you're doing some sort of recursion. The code in the answer should work (see demo here http://codepad.org/ZB7kIyln). Check that you have the `Response` class declared in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

There's no there way, unless you define once css class and put all your echo statements inside it.

```
<div class = "name">
<?php

echo ...
...
...
?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change each `echo` to a fixed variable name:

```
if ($power != "1")
{
    $msg = "Please contact administrator for assistance.";
}

if (!$uid)
{
    $msg = "You do not have permissions to change your status.";
}

if (!$mybb->input['custom'])
{
    $msg = "You've not added any status to change";
}
```

Then write a function for giving style to the out put:

```
function stylizing($msg, $class="")
{
   if($class != "")
       $msg = "<div class='{$class}'>{$msg}</div>";
   echo $msg;
}
```

Then you can use `stylizing($msg, "class_name");` where you want to print out the result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$message = '';

if ($power != "1") $message .= "<div class='one'>Please contact administrator for assistance.</div>";
elseif (!$uid) $message .= "<div class='two'>You do not have permissions to change your status.</div>";
elseif (!$mybb->input['custom']) $message .= "<div class='three'>You've not added any status to change.</div>";

echo $message;
```

Comment: I think they are looking for a solution that allows multiple messages with css classes but without having to update all existing output messages, not a way to limit the message to just one.

Comment: You've to use .= instead += since its PHP

Comment: Yes. Need more coffee.